# Python program to find all prime numbers in the range 1 - n

Tags: python, primes

Hi I know there are lots of solutions to this problem but I wanted some help finding out why my answer is wrong.

Here's my answer:

```
number = int(input("enter a number: "))

for n in range(2, number + 1):
    for i in range(2, number // 2):
        if n == 2:
            print(n)
        elif n % i == 0:
            break
        else:
            print(n)
```

Here's the output on my terminal:

```
> enter a number: 12 
  2 2 2 2 3 5 5 5 7 7 7 7 9 11 11 11 11
```

thankss

Comment: What is the goal of your inner loop?

Comment: Your inner loop should go to n not to number

Comment: the `print(n)` should be outside the inner loop and only if you did not break from it (which means you did not find any divisor). You can use a [for/else](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/for_-_else.html) statement, so the else will only execute if you have never break from the loop. You just need to unindent the else statement one level

Comment: Make the `else` clause part of the inner `for` loop, not part of the `if` statement. You only want to print `n` if that loop completes without finding any `i` for which `n % i == 0`.

Comment: Since you *know* 2 is prime, don't handle that in the loop at all. Just print 2, then start with `for n in range(3, number+1, 2):` (no sense trying the even numbers, either, since you know they are divisible by 2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your solution is that you haven't set up the inner loop properly. The other problem (the lesser one in my opinion) is that the print is inside of your inner loop which causes the multiple prints.

Here is a proper solution:

```
for n in range(2, number + 1):
    isPrime = True
    for i in range(2, n - 1):
        if n % i == 0:
            isPrime = False
    if isPrime:
        print(n)
```

Answer (score 1):

thanks everyone i realised i made a lot of really silly mistakes.

i fixed my code in case anyone else sees this question and wants a solution:

```
number = int(input("enter the number: "))

for n in range(2, number + 1):
    for i in range(2, n):
        if n % i == 0:
            break
    else:
        print(n)
```

Comment: Using a `for ... else` is interesting. If you want to make your code much more efficient, look into the [Sieve of Eratoshnes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes). It is a good coding challenge to implement it.